# TFS2015 VNext build output folders

Tags: tfs

New to TFS but have managed to set up a vNext build definition and am able to trigger a build that executes successfully.

The build output is placed at

> D:\TestAgent_work\c312e966

on the build server. However after every subsequent builds this directory is overwritten with the new build output.

Is there a way of retaining previous builds that include the build version in the folder structure?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "Publish Build Artifacts" task to copy the output to either a UNC share or upload it to the server.

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat using the global build variables